# Using HC05 Bluetooth SerialPort to stream music/voice via Arduino

Tags: arduino, serial, bluetooth, baudrate, bit-rate

I'm considering streaming music/voice over Bluetooth serial link (via HC05) from PC to Arduino. By doing this, there would be no need for a SD card. Here is the questions I have.
Any help is appreciated.

**1-** Arduino Uno doesn't have D2A. Is the `tone.h` library enough for this purpose? Can we use an external D2A instead? What about other Arduinos?

**2-** Maximum supported baud rate for ITead's HC05 is 460800 (datasheet [here](http://www.electronicaestudio.com/docs/istd016A.pdf)).
Based on searching the net, people suggest using a lower baud rate to increase Signal/Noise or even range. Does UART's baud rate(aka a logic layer) affect range/quality?

**3-** If we use 460800, we get 45 KByte/s data rate. If we use 115200, we get 11.25 KByte/s data rate. Are these rates enough for A- Voice and B- Music streaming?

**[UPDATE]**
Various audio quality samples are provided [here](http://streambox.org/elc/theory/quality.htm) (from 8Kbps to 192Kbps).
Here is a list within reach of HC05's maximum baud rate:
1   KByte/s -> [voice](http://streambox.org/elc/theory/samples/sprache_8khz.mp3), [music](http://streambox.org/elc/theory/samples/musik_8khz.mp3)
2   KByte/s -> [voice](http://streambox.org/elc/theory/samples/sprache_16khz.mp3), [music](http://streambox.org/elc/theory/samples/musik_16khz.mp3)
....
10 KByte/s -> [voice](http://streambox.org/elc/theory/samples/sprache_80khz.mp3), [music](http://streambox.org/elc/theory/samples/musik_80khz.mp3)

10 KByte/s or 80 Kbps corresponds to baud rate = 115200 and we can quite clearly hear the contents. So can we say baud rate is not the limiting factor here?

Thanks

Comment: And C, why do you think an Arduino would be any kind of a match for this task?

Comment: Telephone voice (ISDN) is 64kbit per second. That's 8 bit samples, 8000 per second. CD quality is 44100 samples per second at 16 bits per sample - times 2 for stereo. Do the math, and consider how you plan to squeeze that much data through your bluetooth link, and how you expect the Arduino (with no DAC) to do anything useful with it.

Comment: Think about streaming MP3. Try searching "MP3 decoder IC" or "Arduino MP3 decode".

Comment: @JRE What is the technical reason that makes Arduino incapable of this task? I'm also considering an external DAC. And based on bitrates raw numbers,  it seems at least a decent voice connection could be established @  11KBps

Comment: Just for a test, download Audacity, and use it to resample a piece of music or voice to your estimated bit rates.  Have a listen, then decide for yourself whether that is good enough.

Comment: @JRE I've updated my post

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator  BW , SNR and THD is most certainly affects signal integrity. But only you can specify what you need. Shannon's Law defines these tradeoffs for Error Rate and SNR vs BW and you must define what error rate you need in quantifying a "pattern" such as word recognition , or awareness  of background signals or acuity of stereo imaging of position of the violin on stage in a Deutche Grammaphone recording. Each demands different set of specs. THis is why there are so many audio standards for compression BW , sampling rate. such as Variable bit rate (VBR) MP3 or CBR

Comment: Digital Telephone old standard is 8KB/s 8 bit A Law or u Law log curve >70 dB SNR 3kHz BW but high SNR much clearer than cell phones quiet as a CD but log curve ADC/DAC  DS1 and E1 data rates are 64kbps and 8 sample rate synchronous... so many choices. so define BW, SNR and then compression options

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I just want to transmit audio over it. So can I use the maximum baud rate (45KByte/s)?

Comment: it depends on your specs for SNR of both BTE and Audio and effects on range  higher BW demands higher CNR but gives better SNR